# Getting 404 error for string generated URL

Tags: vb.net, rest, url, http-status-code-404, webrequest

Creating Request URL in visual basic. same url will work in the test screen in trello

Hey Guys, So coding a widget that adds a new card to Trello via web API. I have played around in their deveoper portal and the same URL there will work, however when running in visual basic it throws an 404 error when wating for the response. Any help would be appreciated. This is for a school project, so relatively new to it all. Thanks very much.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim cardName As String = name.Text.ToString
    Dim cardtext As String = desc.Text.ToString

    Dim cardUploadURL As String = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards?name=" + cardName + "&desc=" + cardtext + "&pos=top&idList=5b67fe11c8bc945a40b905fe&keepFromSource=all&key=c1b9497af5a50f3392ffe1331863ccab&token=63238f657944a4c276d2d136b8baba6ba0ac78906aa6bfcdb87f469789440feb"
    MessageBox.Show(cardUploadURL)
    dataGet(cardUploadURL)
    MessageBox.Show("card Uploaded")
End Sub

Public Shared Function dataGet(URL As String)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)

    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim data As String
    data = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Return data
End Function
```

End Class
and Error message:

```
  System.Net.WebException 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original posted code, there are lines that are encoding spaces in the URL parameters:

```
cardName = cardName.Replace(" ", "%20")
```

This is not necessary to do with the HttpWebRequest objects - the URL encoding will be handled automatically.

This could be the cause of the 404 - maybe the encoded spaces are being double encoded (or something else, using a tool like fiddler might tell you what's wrong)? Which depending on the api interface being called could cause it to return a 404.

Comment: Hey MarkL, Thanks for your help. However I just check my actual code and the quotation marks weren't there, but it still have me the 404 error. Any other ideas? Cheers

Comment: @M.Green, I'd suggest creating an MCVE with just a few lines of code (webrequest, httpwebrequest, etc), to replicate the problem and investigate it. What is the failing url? If you're receiving a 404, then the url is going to be wrong somehow, almost certainly.

Comment: Ok, thats about as small as I can make it. again, thanks for your help.